# Tcl/Tk: How do I append or insert into a nested list?

Tags: list, tcl

I have two lists - each containing nested lists - that I want to combine into a third list.

When I try to use `lappend` as follows, my new list only contains the elements from my second list, and none of the elements from the first list.

```
% set list1 {{a b c} {d e f} {g h i}}
{a b c} {d e f} {g h i}
% set list2 {{j k l} {m n o} {p q r}}
{j k l} {m n o} {p q r}
% set list3 [lappend [lindex $list1 0] [lindex $list2 0]]
{j k l}
```

I was hoping this would return

```
{a b c j k l}
```

Similarly when I try to use linsert, I get a "bad index" error:

```
% set list3 [linsert [lindex $list1 0] [lindex $list2 0]]
bad index "j k l": must be integer?[+-]integer? or end?[+-]integer?
```

Any thoughts?

Ideally, I'd like to take my two lists, and iterate through each nested list so that my output yields

```
{a b c j k l} {d e f m n o} {g h i p q r}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lappend](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm) command takes as its first argument a list variable name.
You are passing it the name {a b c}.

You can use the [concat](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm) command to join two lists together to create
a single list.

```
set list3 [concat [lindex $list1 0] [lindex $list2 0]]
```

Or create a new list with [list](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm) and expansion:

```
set list3 [list {*}[lindex $list1 0] {*}[lindex $list2 0]]
```

To iterate through the lists, you can use:

```
foreach {item1} $list1 {item2} $list2 {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using concat as opposed to `set list3 "[lindex $list1 0] [lindex $list2 0]"`?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl 8.6 has an operation that lets you `lappend` *one element* directly into a nested list:

```
lset theListVariable $index end+1 $theItemToAdd
```

For example (interactive session):

```
% set lst {a b c d}
a b c d
% lset lst 1 end+1 e
a {b e} c d
% lset lst 1 end+1 f
a {b e f} c d
```

That means we'd do your overall operation like this:

```
set list3 $list1
set index 0
foreach sublist $list2 {
    foreach item $sublist {
        lset list3 $index end+1 $item
    }
    incr index
}
```

Or, more likely through concatenation:

```
set list3 [lmap a $list1 b $list2 {
   list {*}$a {*}$b
}]
```

The use of `list` with expansion of all arguments does list concatenation. You could use `concat` instead, but that sometimes doesn't do list concat (for complicated backward compatibility reasons).

Comment: I like the last bit using lmap.  Unfortunately for me, my app is using Tcl 8.4, and it does not appear lmap is a function in that version of Tcl.  The `concat` suggestion in the other respondent's answer seems to work, but I'm curious about your comment about `concat` having backwards compatibility issues?  Can you elaborate?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

with [`linsert`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/linsert.htm) you would write:

```tcl
set joined [linsert [lindex $list1 0] end {*}[lindex $list2 0]]  ;# => a b c j k l
```

We're specifying we want to insert, at the *end* of the first element of list1, the elements of the first element of list2

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is -

```
% set list1 {{a b c} {d e f} {g h i}}
{a b c} {d e f} {g h i}
% set list2 {{j k l} {m n o} {p q r}}
{j k l} {m n o} {p q r}
% lappend list3 "[lindex $list1 0] [lindex $list2 0]"
{a b c j k l}
```